# How to create a crisp topographical/terrain map with ggplot2?

Tags: r, topography, terrain, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a high quality vector based map (in greyshades) in order to report locations.

I tried this by getting maps from GADM and SRTM to make a raster as a base for plotting in ggplot2. However, the resulting data frame is too large for plotting. Quesion 1: How to simplify the data frame for ggplot2 without while still obtaining a high quality resolution map?

Here is what I tried for south New Zealand:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(scales)
library(rgeos)

nz1 <- getData('GADM', country='NZL', level=1)
nz1 <- subset(nz1,NAME_1 %in% c("Southland","Otago","West Coast"))

nz1c <- gCentroid(nz1) %>% coordinates()

dem1 <- getData("SRTM",lat=nz1c[2],lon=nz1c[1],path=datadir)
dem2 <- getData("SRTM", lat = -45.516667, lon = 168.566667,path=datadir) # City of Athol coordinates
dem3 <- getData("SRTM",lat = -45.866667, lon = 170.5,path=datadir) # City of Dunedin coordinates
dem4 <- getData("SRTM",lat = -44.383333, lon = 168.716667,path=datadir) # Mount Aspiring GPS data -44.383333, 168.716667

dem <- merge(dem1,dem2,dem3,dem4)

dem <- crop(dem,nz1,filename=file.path(datadir,"dem_nz1.tif")

dem.p  <-  rasterToPoints(dem)
df <-  data.frame(dem.p)
colnames(df) = c("lon", "lat", "alt")

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(lon,lat)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = alt))
```

The data frame has about 25 Million observations Which produces something like this (~110MB PDF):[image: ~110MB PDF]

This looks already very promising but it is way too heavy.

How could I possibly reduce the data frame or use any other approach to obtain a nice high scalable vector image for my ggplot2 maps?

I just started working with maps in R and basically I just want to produce nice terrain/topographic maps, and I don't want to use ggmaps or similar for this.

Comment: What is za?  nz1?  Also datadir, nz0c are missing. I would find the right resolution of the entire grid for you final map. After the crop, try  dem1 <- aggregate(dem, fact = 16) and then replot with dem1, then  reduce (or increase) "fact" and try the plot again until you find the level that's right. You can use plot(dem, maxpixels = ncell(dem) / (fact * fact))  to get a faster result without having to create points.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, za should be nz1 and nz0c should be nz1c. Sorry for bad example code. I was just trying to show how I got the coordinates for the STRM rasters.  At least I corrected that for now but as I am not able to test this and your code now, I report back tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I just can't get the downloads to work, can you list the specific links to those files? getData prints out the links when it dowloads. I don't know what the problem is, getData hasn't worked for me for some time.  (Also, your code:  datadir is still missing, and rasterVis is not used. )

Comment: I already tried your suggestion today and it worked quite well. I found fact = 5 to be a suitable compromise. So thanks anyways, that was a great help. However, didn't had time for reworking the script here. I'll change it, hopefully soon, with file links.

Comment: No worries, great!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried lowering the resolution of your raster data before creating the plot? Unfortunately, R is still slow for plotting large images so there is a trade-off between resolution and plotting speed.

```
    # reduce raster resolution
      dem_lower_res <- aggregate(dem, fact=10)
```

then plot

```
dem.p  <-  rasterToPoints(dem_lower_res )
df <-  data.frame(dem.p)
colnames(df) = c("lon", "lat", "alt")

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(lon,lat)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = alt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, efficiency is enabled by the new `terrainmeshr` package, and we convert to gg-ready form with `anglr`.

Just replace `dem` with your data, I couldn't get `getData` to work so I grabbed some AWS tiles.

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(ceramic)
suppressWarnings({
  # whatever you do to get your dem
  el <- cc_location(extent(166, 175, -48, -40), 
                  type = "elevation-tiles-prod", max_tiles = 36)
 dem <- projectRaster(el, crs =  "+proj=longlat") 
 dem[dem<1] <- NA

})
#> Preparing to download: 20 tiles at zoom = 7 from 
#> https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/

library(anglr)
mesh <- as.mesh3d(dem)
## plot3d(mesh)
## fortify ggplot()  
fortify.mesh3d <- function(x, ...) {
  idx <- if (!is.null(x$it)) x$it else x$ib
  nc <- dim(idx)[2L]
  idx <- as.vector(idx)
  xx <- x ## workaround the tibble name-steal
  tibble::tibble(x = xx$vb[1L, idx],
                 y = xx$vb[2L, idx],
                 z = xx$vb[3L, idx],
                 group = rep(seq_len(nc), each = 3L))
}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mesh) + geom_polygon(aes(x, y, group = group, fill = z), colour = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>